# Changing color incrementally

Tags: css

```css
#mainbody :nth-child(1){
    border-color: #FFCC00;
}
#mainbody :nth-child(2) {
    border-color: #FFAA00;
}
#mainbody :nth-child(3) {
    border-color: #FF8800;
}
#mainbody :nth-child(4) {
    border-color: #FF6600;
}
```

This is awkward, especially if you add another 20 children. Would it be possible to use something like this, feeding `calc()` the position and using it in `rgb()`?

Is there another way of doing this? (`counter()`?)

```css
#mainbody h2 {
    border-color: rgb(255, calc( 255 / ( childposition / 4 ) ) ,0);
}
```

The following shows promise but I don't think `rgb()` accepts an internal `counter()`:

```css
body {
    counter-reset: headcolors 255;
}
h2:after {
    counter-increment: headcolors -34;
    content: "rgb(255," counter(headcolors) ",0);";
}
h2 {
    counter-increment: headcolors -34;
    color: rgb(255,counter(headcolors),0);
}
```

Comment: Check out [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) or [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you haven't said that you want a CSS only solution, I would recommend you to use a SASS/LESS based solution.

http://sassmeister.com/gist/925757ff999824ec0270

```
$baseColor: #FFCC00;

@for $i from 1 to 5 {
  #mainbody :nth-child(#{$i}) {
      border-color: adjust-color($baseColor, $green: ($i - 1) * 1);
  }
  $i: $i + 1;
}
```

The above code generates this:

```
#mainbody :nth-child(1) {
  border-color: #ffcc00;
}

#mainbody :nth-child(2) {
  border-color: #ffcd00;
}

#mainbody :nth-child(3) {
  border-color: #ffce00;
}

#mainbody :nth-child(4) {
  border-color: #ffcf00;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Either use JS or one of the options suggested by pradeek. As of now, there is no way to use variables in CSS native language, if not by using `counter-reset` and `counter-increment`, but then you have to use them along with `content`, and that will change the content displayed inside the element, they will not treated as variables to use for operations.

[Read here](http://www.w3.org/People/Bos/CSS-variables) or [here](http://meiert.com/en/blog/20090401/why-css-needs-no-variables/) to understand why variables don't fit with CSS.

Answer (score 2):

With jQuery you can do the following when the page is loaded:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var startfrom = 204; // CC in Hex, the starting value for the green color
    var endto = 255 - startfrom; // the ending value for the green color
    var limit = 4;
    for(var i = 1; i <= limit; i++)
    {
        $("#mainbody :nth-child("+i+")").css("border-color", "rgb(255,"+Math.round(startfrom - (startfrom - endto)*(i-1)/(limit-1))+",0)");
    }
});
```

See the jsfiddle with [4 children](http://jsfiddle.net/kysdN/) and with [20 children](http://jsfiddle.net/9G7fU/)

Comment: you might consider removing `:nth-child` from this, as if it could be avoided you could use this in IE8 and below I believe. side note, already awarded the bounty, though I did upvote.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your hex values, you are essentially just changing the hue by 8 each time. ie:

```
#ffcc00 = HSL: 48° 100% 50%
#ffaa00 = HSL: 40° 100% 50%
#ff8800 = HSL: 32° 100% 50%
```

etc.

So this is how you would go about doing this in LESS:

```
@base: #ffcc00;
@numChildren: 5;
.loop(@counter, @color) when (@counter <= @numChildren) {

  h2:nth-child(@{counter}) {
    border: 5px solid @color;
  }
  @newColor: hsl(hue(@color) - 8, 100%, 50%);
  .loop((@counter + 1),@newColor);    // next iteration
}
.loop(1,@base); // launch the loop
```

**[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/danield770/pen/tpDle)**

The above codepen would assume markup something like so (5 children):

```
<div class="mainBody">
  <h2>one</h2>
  <h2>two</h2>
  <h2>three</h2>
  <h2>four</h2>
  <h2>five</h2>
</div>
```

and produces the following CSS:

```
h2:nth-child(1) {
  border: 5px solid #ffcc00;
}
h2:nth-child(2) {
  border: 5px solid #ffaa00;
}
h2:nth-child(3) {
  border: 5px solid #ff8800;
}
h2:nth-child(4) {
  border: 5px solid #ff6600;
}
h2:nth-child(5) {
  border: 5px solid #ff4400;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firefox 31+ or 29+(width [options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables)) issue([`fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/Cp92V/)):

HTML:

```
<div>
    <p><p><p><p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
::root {
    --bg-color: #000000;
}

div :nth-child(1){
    --bg-color: #FFCC00;
}
div :nth-child(2) {
    --bg-color: #FFAA00;
}
div :nth-child(3) {
    --bg-color: #FF8800;
}
div :nth-child(4) {
    --bg-color: #FF6600;
}

p {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: var(--bg-color);
}
```

As @Jose said, `counter` function used only for `content` property. But `vars` a now enabled in CSS. `Chrome` and `Firefox` has different syntax. There are two specs of [W3C CSS Variables Module Level 1](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-css-variables-20120410/)(Chrome implementation) and [CSS Custom Properties for Cascading Variables Module Level 1](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-variables/)(Firefox implementation).