# Incrementally change the color of text using CSS?

Tags: css

Given I have the following CSS:

```
p { color: #ccc }
```

And the text

```
<p class="grey">I'm extremely angry!</p>
```

I would like to change the color of the text by adding a class that increasing the red value of its color...*in an additive way.*

I.e. I don't want to change the color of the text to red.  I want to **make the existing color of the text redder**.

Is this possible using CSS alone?  Something like:

```
p.redder { color-increment: #c00 }
```

Comment: Have you thought of using Javascript?

Comment: maybe take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8271271/changing-color-incrementally

Comment: @Tim, unfortunately im using this with a JS word cloud library that lets me dump out a class, but not inline JS.

Comment: @brobken thanks, that got me onto the idea of CSS transitions which I'm exploring

Comment: I'm glad it could help you out!

Comment: maybe you want to use hsl() colors: test http://codepen.io/anon/pen/htFkv/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% CSS solution (99%), but you can achieve something like that using [transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions). The only "non-CSS" part is dynamically changing a class. But that's the closest you can get.

CSS

```
p { color: #ccc }
p.red {
    color: #c00;
    transition: all 10s linear; // <-- this is the key
}
```

JS

```
document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].classList.add('red');
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/vek4d/

So basically, it sets a 10-second animation in motion as soon as the class changes.

---

So, if you really want to go crazy with that, I have another idea.

You can do masking - simply duplicate your paragraph and put a fully-red and transparent copy on top of it. Then, to increase the redness, just tweak the opacity of the mask element. Here's an example (note I'm using 75% instead of 15% to make it more obvious): http://jsfiddle.net/vek4d/1/

Comment: Very cool.  One issue though is I don't want the color to end up #c00.  I want it to increase its existing colors red value by some percentage.

Comment: Well, any color you want has to have its HEX value, no? I mean, just change the end color to the one you want. What are you trying to achieve with all that? Maybe there's a better solution.

Comment: Lets say class A's text color is rgb(100,100,100).  I want another class called X that will increase that color by 15% to rgb(115,100,100).  Similarly if class B's color is rgb(50,50,50), and I apply X to it, red value will increase by 15% to rgb(57,50,50).

Comment: But you still have a finite number of classes, and you can calculate the "redness" variation for each, right? I'll show you another idea in my answer.

Comment: Sounds like this is about the closest we can get now.  Thanks @Shomz

Comment: I'm not really a fan of duplicating anything, but if it works for you, just do it! You're welcome.